# Count the containing entities with cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

im stuck while trying to count the entities and order the set of results after that.

I have connected the models to each other:

```php
// ProductsTable
  $this->belongsToMany('Users', [
    'through' => 'ProductsUsers',
    'join_table' => 'products_users'
  ]
  );

// UsersTable
  $this->hasMany('Products', [
    'through' => 'ProductsUsers',
    ]
  );

// ProductsUsersTable
  $this->belongsTo('Users');
  $this->belongsTo('Products');
```

By this Query, I get the Products including the users:

```
    $products =  $this->Products->find()
        ->contain([
            'Users',
            'ProductCategories'
        ]);
```

It looks like that:

```
Products
 -> Product 1
  -> User1, User2, User 3
 -> Product 2
  -> User1, User 3
```

Now I want to sort the result. But my tries fail.

I tried this:

```
    $products =  $this->Products->find()
        ->contain([
            'Users',
            'ProductCategories'
        ])
    ->select([
        'users_count' => $this->Products->find()->func()->count('Users')
    ])->order(['users_count' => 'asc'])
    ->select($this->Products);
```

But no success. $Products->users_count includes all users.

I would be happy for any hint.

Comment: If I understand correctly.. You want to count the users belonging to the products?

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Counter Cache](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html):

> It is possible though to make this work for belongsToMany associations. You need to enable the CounterCache behavior in a custom through table configured in association options. See how to configure a custom join table Using the ‘[through](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option)’ Option.

This eliminates the need to compute on the fly and you have a field for user & product count in products & users table respectively.